# Begin every chapter on a new page using LyX

Tags: page-breaking, lyx, chapters

I'm writing a document in LyX (an editor for LaTeX) and I need every chapter to begin on a new page (not necessarily an odd one). Right now it just puts every chapter one after the other.

How can I do this in LyX?

Comment: Can't you use Insert -> Page break?

Comment: Most document classes will have chapters start on new pages by default. What class are you using?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

As Seamus commented, most classes already start chapters on a new page. This requires using the `\chapter` command.

However, if you use `\section` commands, page breaks would not automatically happen, this is not very common for smaller sections. But you can define it, by this modification in your LyX document preamble:

```
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{\clearpage\stdsection}
```

The first line stores the original `\section` command with a different name, then `\section` is redefined to include a `\clearpage` before. A good effect is, that `\clearpage` forces figures and tables to be printed out before the next page is started, so they don't float into the next section. That's why I did not use just `\newpage`.

However, I strongly recommend using a class with `\chapter` commands, such as `book`, `report`, `memoir`, `scrbook` or `scrreprt`. The last two are from the great KOMA-Script bundle.